# Preloading fonts in CSS File

Tags: css, preload

i have a font-awesome CSS-Fille which i load in the footer of my website. In the CSS File the fonts are loaded kike this:

```
font-display:swap;src:url(../webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot);src:url(../webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot?#iefix) 
format("embedded-opentype"),url(../webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2) format("woff2"),url(../webfonts/fa- 
brands-400.woff) format("woff"),url(../webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf)......
```

not i look for an solution to preload these fonts. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if thats what you mean, but you can define a [font-face](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) in a seperate css file, e.g.:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: faBrands;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('/webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: faBrands;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('/webfonts/fa-brands-500.eot');
}
```

Assuming the folder `webfonts` is under `public`, you can then write in a css file:

`font-family: faBrands;`

Just make sure to import the font face css file first.